# curl script just filling up form not submitting it

Tags: php, curl

I have written a script in PHP cURL to fill form.
but strangely the form is only getting filled and there is no submission of form

here is the code
please help

```
$cookies = 'C:\wamp\www\costie\cookies.txt';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url1); // set url to post to 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); // times out after Ns 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // set POST method 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=$value1&__PREVIOUSPAGE=$value2&__EVENTVALIDATION=$value3&$name1=2008&$name2=02-33-255-009&$name3=&$name4=&$name5=");//ADD post fields

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process 
curl_close($ch); 
echo $result;
```

Comment: cURL is actually doing the form submission, so `$url1` should be the URL that goes in the `target` attribute of the form, it shouldn't point to the form itself (assuming they're different).

Comment: @Barmar i have used the action attribute of form element

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant (brain fart). How does that script know whether to fill in the form or submit it? If it looks for a hidden form field, make sure you're including that in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: @Barmar yes all hidden fields are included. but what is happening is that fields are getting filled all right but form is not getting submitted

Comment: @Barmar ok i got your point. now i am going thru the website code and look for target values linked to the form. Thank you your help is appreciated